# How to avoid a scenario in which finally block does not execute

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was asked in an interview that when finally block does not execute. I replied that when JVM shuts down abruptly before the finally is called or when System.exit() is called. Then I was asked how can we avoid that scenario so that our program always remain executing. That is such a scenario should be handled. Can we handle such a scenario. If yes how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even finally fails but still shutdownhook will be executed.

Answer is -

```
Runtime#addShutdownHook
```

> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of
>   events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or    when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt,    such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or
>     system shutdown.

[Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

Code -

```
Runtime.addShutdownHook(new Thread {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Just before going down..");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you kill your system with a big enough gun, it will eventually stop being nice to you. You would have to have a redundant system in order for your code to keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Java tutorial on oracle website says.

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This
>   ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected
>   exception occurs.
>
> Note: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed,
>   then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread
>   executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally
>   block may not execute even though the application as a whole
>   continues.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html