# Using try-catch with resources properly

Tags: java

**Java 1.7** has *try-catch with resources* which handles *closeable* resources by itself. Means that, when the try-catch block executed, resources are automatically closed.

I am confused about how try-catch block ends. Consider the following two scenarious.

Case 1:

```
void function()
{
    try (closable)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {}

    //at this point, the closable variable is closed
    //by try-catch statement. No issues and it's clear.
}
```

Case 2:

```
void function()
{
    try (closable)
    {
        doSomething();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {}

    //we never reached to this point, and this what 
    //makes me think.Is closable really closed before 
    //return statement or do we need to manually call 
    //closable.close() before returning?
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is closable really closed before return statement or do we need to manually call closable.close() before returning?

Yes, it's called for you automatically.

To verify this for yourself, you can put a breakpoint inside your `closeable` object's `close()` method and run you application in `debug` mode. Right after the `return;` executes, you should see the JVM halting its execution inside the `close()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is closed.

This:

```
try(Resource r = new Resource()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

works almost the same way as this: (it acts differently if `close` throws an exception)

```
Resource r = new Resource();
try {
    // do stuff
} finally {
    r.close();
}
```

and `finally` blocks are executed if you return from the middle of a `try` block, or leave it by getting to the end, or throw an exception from inside it, or jump out of it with `break` or `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use finally block for confirmation,  finally block will always execute, so you can make double check at finally block:-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

```
finaly
{
if(!r.closed)
r.close();
}
```

Note :- finally will not work in following scenarios  [How to avoid a scenario in which finally block does not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773272/how-to-avoid-a-scenario-in-which-finally-block-does-not-execute)

Answer (score 0):

Try with resources is the same as using the finally block prior to JDK 7.

```
finally {
        if (resource != null) resource.close();
    }
```

So the answer is: The resource is clodes after leaving the try/catch/finally block.

Answer (score 0):

You never reach the point after the try-catch block in the second example because you return from your method. The closable will be closed though.

> void close()
>              throws Exception
>
> Closes this resource, relinquishing any underlying resources. This
>   method is invoked automatically on objects managed by the
>   try-with-resources statement.
>
> While this interface method is declared to throw Exception,
>   implementers are strongly encouraged to declare concrete
>   implementations of the close method to throw more specific exceptions,
>   or to throw no exception at all if the close operation cannot fail.
>
> Implementers of this interface are also strongly advised to not have
>   the close method throw InterruptedException. This exception interacts
>   with a thread's interrupted status, and runtime misbehavior is likely
>   to occur if an InterruptedException is suppressed. More generally, if
>   it would cause problems for an exception to be suppressed, the
>   AutoCloseable.close method should not throw it.
>
> Note that unlike the close method of Closeable, this close method is
>   not required to be idempotent. In other words, calling this close
>   method more than once may have some visible side effect, unlike
>   Closeable.close which is required to have no effect if called more
>   than once. However, implementers of this interface are strongly
>   encouraged to make their close methods idempotent.
>
> Throws:
>       Exception - if this resource cannot be closed

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close%28%29).